# How to convert DateTime to string in C# using Oracle date format

Tags: c#, oracle, datetime, format, converters

### Goal

Convert a `DateTime` to `string` using an Oracle datetime format[1] like "IY-IW".

### Description

I have a situation where I'm provided a `DateTime` and an Oracle date format string.
The result should be a `string` containing the date and time in the format specified by the Oracle date format.

In short, I would need the method below

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts a datetime to a string with the format specified by the Oracle date format.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="oracleDateFormat">
/// Datetime format specified in http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php
/// </param>
/// For example:
/// dateTimeToConvert = 2014-09-23T10:09:47.7739125+02:00, oracleNlsDateFormat = "IY-IW" => result == "14-38"
public string ConvertDateTimeToString(DateTime dateTimeToConvert, string oracleDateFormat);
```

If done in a database query, I would have used the Oracle to_char method. However, I need to do the conversion in the C# environment.

- [C# How to parse a string of date in an arbitrary specified Oracle date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476632/c-sharp-how-to-parse-a-string-of-date-in-an-arbitrary-specified-oracle-date-form)
- [How to format a date from Oracle to a valid datetime in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848777/how-to-format-a-date-from-oracle-to-a-valid-datetime-in-c-sharp)

The questions above are on the right track but still doesn't give a solution to my problem. For instance, providing DateTime.ParseExact with the format "IY-IW" raises a FormatException.

Is there a simple way to achieve the goal? Like using DateTime.ParseExact and somehow specifying that an Oracle date format is used? Or converting the Oracle datetime format to C# datetime format on some way[2]?

If yes, how would that solution look like?

### Notes and references

1. The Oracle date format specification: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php
2. Creating a method mapping Oracle datetime formats to C# datetime formats would be possible but I don't consider it being a good or simple solution.

Comment: What is the purpose of this? The main reason I can think of would be: to concatenate the value into sql - but: a parameter would be a far better option

Comment: The `DateTime` value comes from the database where it is stared as a `Date`. The Oracle datetime format is specified by the user of the application. Historically this format has been specified in the Oracle form. Basically the date is to be shown to the user in the form the user prefers.

Was this answer to your question, @MarcGravell? Otherwise I'm afraid I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to achieve the goal?

Almost certainly not.

> Like using DateTime.ParseExact and somehow specifying that an Oracle date format is used?

No - .NET doesn't know about the Oracle date/time format.

> Converting the Oracle datetime format to C# datetime format on some way?

That would be my first suggestion. In particular:

- If you only need to support a small number of these formats, it may be worth hard-coding the ones you support
- Even if you need to be a bit more flexible than that, I wouldn't try to support *everything* Oracle supports
- You may well still run into significant issues around `IW` or other week-based formats. (`DateTime` doesn't support ISO week-years.)

I would *attempt* to remove the requirement in the first place, however. Wherever possible try to avoid encoding dates as strings in the first place - if you're providing a date to the database, provide it *as* a `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset` via a parameter. We don't know enough about your context to know whether or not that's an option, but it's worth spending a bit of time trying to remove the requirement if you can.

Comment: Thanks. With your answer in mind, I will try to solve the problem by working around the limitations in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
string oracleDateString = dateTimeToConvert.ToString(oracleDateFormat);
```

Comment: But when `oracleDateFormat == "IY-IW"`, the resulting `oracleDateString` would be "IY-IW" and not "14-38" so that solution doesn't seem to work.